# NgRx state returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, state-management

I can't see a list of users in my application. Everything worked fine since I've updated the routing importing the modules using lazy loading. If I open the chrome developer console and I open up the Redux tab, it shows me the correct state and the list of users. But something is broken in between.
My UsersListComponent is this one:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UsersService} from "../service/users.service";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import {loadUsers} from "../store/user-actions.action";
import {AppState} from "../store/user-store.store";
import {selectUsers, selectUsersError, selectUsersLoaded} from "../store/user-selectors.selector";
import {map, tap} from "rxjs/operators";

export interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  gender: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'users-list',
  templateUrl: './users-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users-list.component.scss']
})
export class UsersListComponent implements OnInit {
  loaded$: Observable<boolean> = new Observable<boolean>();
  error$: Observable<boolean> = new Observable<boolean>();
  users$: Observable<User[]> = new Observable<User[]>();

  constructor(private postsService: UsersService, private store: Store<AppState>) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loaded$ = this.store.select(selectUsersLoaded);
    this.users$ = this.store.select(selectUsers);
    this.error$ = this.store.select(selectUsersError).pipe(
      tap(error => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      }),
      map(error => !!error)
    );
    this.store.dispatch(loadUsers());
  }

}
```

Here's the actions:

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import {User} from "../users-list/users-list.component";

export const loadUsers = createAction('[User] Load Users');

export const loadUsersSuccess = createAction(
  '[User] Load Users Success',
  props<{ users: User[] }>()
);

export const loadUsersFailure = createAction(
  '[User] Load Users Failure',
  props<{ error: any }>()
);

export const loadUserSuccess = createAction(
  '[User] Load Users Success',
  props<{ user: User }>()
);

export const loadUserById = createAction(
  '[User] Load User By Id',
  props<{ id: string }>()
);

export const loadUserByIdSuccess = createAction(
  '[User] Load User By Id Success',
  props<{ user: User }>()
);

export const loadUserByIdFailure = createAction(
  '[User] Load User By Id Failure',
  props<{ error: any }>()
);
```

The effects:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Actions, createEffect, ofType} from '@ngrx/effects';
import {catchError, filter, map, mergeMap, tap, withLatestFrom} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {of} from 'rxjs';
import {
  loadUserById, loadUserByIdFailure, loadUserByIdSuccess,
  loadUsers,
  loadUsersFailure,
  loadUsersSuccess,
  loadUserSuccess
} from "./user-actions.action";
import {UsersService} from "../service/users.service";
import {AppState} from "./user-store.store";
import {Store} from "@ngrx/store";
import {selectSelectedUser, selectUsersLoaded} from "./user-selectors.selector";

@Injectable()
export class UserEffects {
  loadUsers$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(loadUsers),
      withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectUsersLoaded)),
      filter(([action, usersLoaded]) => !usersLoaded),
      tap(() => console.log('loadUsers$ effect started')),
      mergeMap(() =>
        this.userService.getUsers().pipe(
          map(users => loadUsersSuccess({ users })),
          catchError(error => of(loadUsersFailure({ error })))
        )
      )
    )
  );

  loadSelectedUser$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(loadUserById),
      withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectSelectedUser)),
      mergeMap(([action, selectedUser]) => {
        if (selectedUser && selectedUser.id.toString() === action.id) {
          return of(loadUserByIdSuccess({ user: selectedUser }));
        } else {
          return this.userService.getUser(action.id).pipe(
            map(user => loadUserByIdSuccess({ user })),
            catchError(error => of(loadUserByIdFailure({ error })))
          );
        }
      })
    )
  );

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private userService: UsersService,
    private store: Store<AppState>
  ) {}
}
```

The reducer:

```
import {createReducer, on} from '@ngrx/store';
import {loadUserByIdSuccess, loadUsersFailure, loadUsersSuccess, loadUserSuccess} from "./user-actions.action";
import {User} from "../users-list/users-list.component";

export interface UserState {
  users: User[];
  selectUsersLoaded: boolean;
  selectedUser: User | undefined;
  error: boolean;
}

export const initialState: UserState = {
  users: [],
  selectUsersLoaded: false,
  selectedUser: undefined,
  error: false
};

export const userReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(loadUsersSuccess, (state, { users }) => {
    const newState = { ...state, users, selectUsersLoaded: true };
    console.log("newState after loadUsersSuccess: ", newState);
    return newState;
  }),
  on(loadUsersFailure, (state, { error }) => {
    const newState = { ...state, error };
    console.log("newState after loadUsersFailure: ", newState);
    return newState;
  }),
  on(loadUserByIdSuccess, (state, { user }) => ({ ...state, selectedUser: user })),
);
```

The selector:

```
import {createSelector} from '@ngrx/store';
import {AppState} from "./user-store.store";
import {UserState} from "./user-reducer.reducer";

export const selectUserState = (state: AppState) => {
  return state.user;
};

export const selectUsers = createSelector(
  selectUserState,
  (state: UserState) => {
    console.log("state", state);
    return state.users
  }
);

export const selectUsersLoaded = createSelector(
  selectUserState,
  (state: UserState) => state.selectUsersLoaded
);

export const selectUsersError = createSelector(
  selectUserState,
  (state: UserState) => state.error
);

export const selectSelectedUser = createSelector(
  selectUserState,
  (state: UserState) => state.selectedUser
);
```

And the store:

```
import { ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';
import {userReducer, UserState} from "./user-reducer.reducer";
import {UserEffects} from "./user-effect.effect";

export interface AppState {
  user: UserState;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  user: userReducer
};

export const effects = [UserEffects];
```

My users module has been loaded using lazy loading in this way in the `app-routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/users', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: 'users',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./users/users.module').then(m => m.UsersModule)
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/login' }
];
```

In the UsersModule I put the following imports:

```
...
StoreModule.forFeature('user', reducers),
EffectsModule.forFeature(effects),
...
```

and in the `app.module.ts`

these:

```
...
EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
StoreModule.forRoot(userReducers),
StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: environment.production })
```

To have the full picture, this is the UsersList HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="loaded$ | async; else loading">
  <ng-container *ngIf="error$ | async; else usersListError">
    <div>An error occurred while loading users.</div>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="!(error$ | async)">
    <mat-list role="list">
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let user of users$ | async" [routerLink]="['detail', user.id]">
        {{user.name}}
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loading>
  <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #usersListError>
  <div>Unable to load users. Please try again later.</div>
</ng-template>
```

`loaded$` is undefined and `users$` too. But, the redux developer tool returns the users state correctly with all users. I don't know what's wrong here